VSCode extension api - How can I get the files list importing the current active file?
Say there is an active file. If I run the command, I wish all the files that are importing the currently active file are shown on the console.
The active file is not always being imported by its absolute path, but can be a relative path.
For example
// hello.js
export const hello = () => 'world'

// importing-file-{n}.js
import {hello} from '/my/absolute/path';
// or
import {hello} from '../hello.js';
// or (and so on)
import {hello} from '../../hello.js';

The first step I want to achieve is when I run the command, I wish that all the files importing hello.js are printed.
importing-file-1.js
importing-file-2.js
...

How can I do that?

find the absolute/relative path of current file, walk over all your workspace files, analyze there import statements and show the file if they import from active file

@rioV8 That sounds one way to solve but I have too many files to walk over.

how do you think to get all imports without reading the files, you do the walk over in an extension script

@rioV8 Just like a built-in feature find reference  shows the list of referencing file, I thought there is an API to do so. If the feature is implemeneted as a way you suggested, I would have to do the same.

how do you think the Language server keeps track of the references: It needs to read the files, build an AST and keep record of what it finds. If you immediately when opening a project ask the references you don't get it or you have to wait till the LS has done its background work
